# Out of memory while restoring, Even though though there is space in memory

Tags: postgresql, psql, pg-dump

I have taken a database backup from the server using:

```
pg_dump -U postgres -d machine -s --disable-triggers >aftrn.sql
```

When I am trying to restore that data into my local using:

```
psql -U postgres -d usernet < aftrn.sql
```

I am getting the following error of:

```
invalid command \N
invalid command \N
invalid command \N
out of memory
root@lap-DB3:/home/akhiles#
```

Does anyone know what's the reason or error related to?

Comment: did you solve the problem?

Answer (score 1):

When I've had this issue, it is because it's been loading into the wrong database.

Pipe the output to a file and read the first few lines of the output.

Comment: How can it be dumped into the wrong database, When we are mentioning the -d parameter in restore?